# How do I change a background image according to a selection?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have a category model with several integer selections to choose from, i.e:

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quote
  belongs_to :subscriber

  CATEGORY_TYPE = {
    1 => "Food",
    2 => "Fun",
    3 => 'Cats',
  }

end
```

view code:

```
<div class="landing-bg2 size">
<div class="styled email-input2">
    <%= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>
    <% if @subscriber.errors.any? %>
      <div class="errorExplanation" style="color: white;">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@subscriber.errors.count, 'error') %> encountered with your email:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @subscriber.errors.full_messages.each do |m| %>
      <li><%= m %></li>
     <% end %>
     </ul>
     </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :subscriber, @subscriber.build_category do |cat| %>
  <%= cat.select(:category_type, Category::CATEGORY_TYPE.map{|p| [p[1], p[0]]}, {prompt: 'Please select'}, {class: 'styled email-input2'}) %>
  <% end %>
</div>

</div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 email-input" style="text-align: center;">
  <p>
  <%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Enter your email", class: "email-input"  %>
  </p>

  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="get_quotes">
     <%= f.submit "Get quotes", class: "get_quotes btn-danger" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div<
```

When a visitor clicks Cats for example, I'd like the background image to change to cats, and when they click Food i'd like the background to change to an image of food.

How might I accomplish this? As you can see the entire view page is wrapped in a landing-bg2 class.

The css for that is:

```
.landing-bg2 {
    background: asset-url("303342.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Please advise! :)

Answer (score 1):

use some `jquery` to change background image like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#cat_category_type).change(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      if(value == "cats")
      {
         $('.landing-bg2').style.css = "background: asset-url('cats.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;"
       }
      if(value=="dogs")
      {
         $('.landing-bg2').style.css = "background: asset-url('dogs.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;"
      }
  etc.....
   })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Choco, I just tried this but it doesn't seem to be working :( can you double check the JQuery code to see if it's O.K

Comment: @SonnyBlack I just added some sample code change your ids according to your requirement

Comment: i did, it looks like the the code is missing a ; or something hmm. Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: @SonnyBlack can you add your original jquery code now

Comment: @SonnyBlack when we are applying background image style the quotes were misplaced. I have edited my answer once check it